# Difference between duplicated Records and Similar Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know in rails model there is a method called validate_uniqueness_of.

I would like to understand how does Rails knows that a specific record is duplicated? What if the user chose the same options or data from yesterday or last last week?

Comment: Uniqueness validation is based on a field of the record, not to all the fields: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of The uniqueness of the record is granted by the index. Maybe you have a specific case to review?

Comment: That's right! Well, I was wondering for example. I'm trying to avoid duplicated records that might happen, I send a record now, and after half an hour I send another one, with the same data. (And I would like to treat this kind of data as duplicated), because for Rails they are two different records, but not in the common sense, I don't know if its possíble, in Rails maybe is no that big deal though.

Comment: If you use default migrations, records are also timestamped: `created_at` and `updated_at` so it's another uniqueness system. If you want to check for uniqueness for custom fields you need to use a callback: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/active_record_validations_callbacks.html. Or I don't get your point?

Comment: I see. You are right. Im gonna make some tests and I let you know if it works. Thanks man

Comment: Please add more context to your question. I see from your comment on an answer that you're building an e-commerce site and are trying to prevent users from ordering the same item more than once. This is probably not a validation issue...but, in any case, please explain your particular problem in your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out `find_or_create_by`? This allows you to either find a record with certain atteributes, or create a new one based on the data.

So for instance. consider the following:

```
u = User.find_or_create_by(name:"Test", email:"test@test.com")

# while later
u = User.find_or_create_by(name:"Test", email:"test@test.com")
```

This will effectively be the same record, the second call will only query the record, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: I guess I was complicating a bit. Its a website where you buy things. I was wondering what if the person wants to buy the same things he bought yesterday... because its the same records, but it should not be deleted in this case. However, I want that the system doesnt allow when you make the checkout twice ... i guess is a datetime thing.. Im gonna test this one you wrote.. thanks for your help

Comment: There's also a unique ID right? So you don't have to worry if someone orders the same thing on the same day, or the next.